# Parse Azure search query filter

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, odata, azure-cognitive-search

My server works as a proxy for a user's search request. Before requesting data on Azure we need to ensure everything is secure. For this we add certain filters into the query filter.
Let's say my server receives this query:

```
search=&$top=10&$filter=customer/customerId gt 1 and customer/customerId lt 5
```

I want to break it apart, investigate it's filter piece by piece and inject a security filter into it.

First thing I do is I get the filter:

```
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
var filter = parsed["$filter"];
```

Next, I want to process it in order to verify and make changes.
After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461905/how-to-parse-odata-filter-with-regular-expression-in-c) I am trying to utilize `ODataUriParser` like so:

```
// 1. Create a dummy model 
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var model = new EdmModel();

    EdmEntityType customer = new EdmEntityType("Namespace", "Customer");
    customer.AddKeys(customer.AddStructuralProperty("CustomerId", EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int32));
    model.AddElement(customer);

    return model;
}


// 2. Utilize it
static void Foo()
{
    var query = "search=&$top=5001&$filter=Customer/CustomerId eq 1";


    var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
    var filter = parsed["$filter"];

    var result = new ODataUriParser(HardCodedTestModel.TestModel, new Uri(filter, UriKind.Relative));
    var parsedFilter = result.ParseFilter();
}
```

This throws an exception to me, saying:

> Unhandled exception.
> Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException: Resource not
> found for the segment 'Customer

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there more easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EDM model doesn't appear to include an [entity set](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_DataModel), so it's not clear what the filter is filtering. Azure Cognitive Search defines an EDM model for each index that includes an entity set "docs", the type of which corresponds to the index definition. The property path `Customer/CustomerId` in the filter would be interpreted by Azure Cognitive Search as the `CustomerId` sub-field of a top-level `Edm.ComplexType` field named `Customer` (Using OData terminology, the document is the entity, `Customer` is a Complex property, and `CustomerId` is a property of `Customer`). Your EDM model will have to include all this schema information if you want to use `ODataUriParser` or `ODataQueryOptionParser` to obtain a semantic AST from the filter text.

That said, you probably don't need a full semantic AST to verify the security of the filter expression (assuming you're trying to defend against things like injection attacks). It might be simpler to use the [lexical stage](https://github.com/brjohnstmsft/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Core/UriParser/Parsers/UriQueryExpressionParser.cs) of the OData filter parser by itself. Then you can process the syntactic AST.

If you want maximum control, you can always roll your own parser. The full BNF for OData is [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt).

Comment: Hey Bruce. Thank you for your answer, I went by `Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser`. I managed to check the initial filter and inject my security filters into it. Using `ISyntacticTreeVisitor` I implemented two visitors. One is for the security injections and another one for parsing the AST back into string OData query. Although, I feel like my approach is not ideal. And that there should be ready-to-go tool to convert `QueryToken` into back into string. I've been looking throughout the Internet but failed to find anything. Could you advise on it, please?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing libraries that do this. I think rolling your own visitor is the way to go (it's what Azure Cognitive Search does internally for debugging our OData filter processor).